# Pointer arithmetic to fill dynamically allocated array in C

Tags: c, pointers, dynamic, malloc, allocation

I allocated an array using `malloc` and than tried filling it using a for loop and pointer arithmetic, It's not working for some reason though.

```
int* myArray = (int*)malloc(100*sizeof(int));

for (int i = 0; i < 100 ; i++)
{
    *myArray = i;
    myArray++;      
}
```

Comment: Could you explain what is not working?

Comment: Usually after you initialize a pointer you don't add to it to increment through the data. Usually you just do `myArray[ELEMENT] = val`. Pointers work just like arrays. Just a thought.

Comment: You should declare i outside the for loop.

Comment: It is working. Are you expecting `myArray`, the pointer, to have the same value after the loop as before the loop???

Comment: @Quirliom: why?  That's valid C99 and C11 code.

Comment: yeah this is in C99, hence the counter declaration in the for loop.

Comment: I wonder how you access the array after incrementing the array pointer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you do `myArray++` you lose the original pointer to the allocated memory.

Instead you should probably do:

```
*(myArray + i) = i;
```

Or even just use normal array indexing:

```
myArray[i] = i;
```

Comment: yeah, the indexing is fine, I wrote it that way originally, just wanted to try pointers.
thanks, I hadent relized that I am progressing the pointer without at least creating a temp to hold the initial position. it works now.

Comment: +1 super simple answer. the myArray[ELEMENT] format is more widely used because when extra arithmatic gets added in *(myArray + ELEMENT ...) can get sloppy.